# Can't call contract method/function from another contract but can call directly

Tags: solidity, embark

In Embark, programming in Solidity.

I have a contract, which is called by another contract. The function it calls is below. Whenever I perform a write command I get a "VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas."

But when I perform write commands in the original contract and not remote contract it doesn't happen even if the writes are much larger.

I think there is an issue I am unaware of. I can read from the contract with out a problem, I just can't write.

```
mapping(uint64 => IDCard) clientIds;

function createIDSpecific(uint64 clientIDi){
  if (!clientIds[clientIDi].initalized){
    clientIds[clientIDi].initalized = true;
    clientIds[clientIDi].owner = msg.sender;
    clientIds[clientIDi].ownershipTransfer.transfered = true;
  }
}
```

The function work fine when I call it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying the gas value by using the options object as the last parameter when calling the transaction. e.g `YourContract.method(your_args, {gas: 800000})`